# How to modify assembly to get more reference?

Tags: assembly, mips, assemblies, pipeline, cpu-architecture

I am pretty much new to the concept of assembly, wanted to know how or where should I be focusing to get few things done

```
     1)modify the code above to handle vectors with 96 elements.
     2)How can i know the data reference generated.
     3)How can i know the instruction reference generated
```

the vector Y = a * X + Y. Vectors X and Y contain 96 double floats each and are stored at addresses Rx and Ry, respectively.  A double float takes 8 bytes (64 bits). Assuming that registers can contain 64 bits and that the CPU can load/store a double float by generating only one address (reference)

```
L.D F0, a
    ADDI    R4, Rx, #512 : last address to load 

Loop:   L.D F2, 0(Rx)         : load X(i)
        MUL.D   F2, F2, F0         : a x X(i)
        L.D F4, 0(Ry)         :load Y(i)
        ADD.D   F4, F4, F2         : a x X(i)   + Y(i)
        S.D F4, 0(Ry)         : store into Y(i) 
        ADDI    Rx, Rx, #8        : increment index to X
        ADDI    Ry, Ry, #8         : increment index to Y
        SUB R20, R4, Rx     : compute bound
        BNEZ    R20, Loop        : check if done
```

Comment: Hi Smple_V, we'd like to help but I guess we are not attending the same school/university. As such, what your teacher/professor means by *instruction reference generated* (and *data reference*) must be translated to something understandable in the question-self-confined context. Simply put: I don't know what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About 1)

The code has a "loop". The `BNEZ    R20, Loop` instruction will change the execution flow to the instruction after `Loop:` label, when `R20` is not equal to zero.

So you should first figure out, how the value of `R20` is calculated, and how many times the loop will execute.

To give you some hint: it's a nice power of two value close to your desired 96, and figuring it out will require you to understand how pointer (address) arithmetic works and why the information about element size being 8 bytes was important.

Then you can adjust one constant in source to make it loop 96 times.